# How to simplify $\ln |\ln y | = \ln|x|+C$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms

Let's say after solving an ODE, the solution I ended up with is as follows,

$$\ln |\ln y | = \ln | x | + C$$

and I want to simplify it in a manner where I can get $y$ by itself. How would I go about that?

Comment: exponentiate both sides twice

Comment: @mathworker21 so it would be $y=e^{xe^{C_{1}}}$?

Answer (score 1):

Exponentiate once and absorb the sign from removing the absolute values and the exponential of the constant into a new constant, $C_1=sign(x_0)sign(\ln y_0)e^C$, then
$$
\ln y=C_1x
$$
which then obviously implies
$$
y=e^{C_1x}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

From $\ln |\ln y | = \ln | x | + C$, we get $|\ln y|=e^C|x|$ from which $y=e^{\pm e^Cx}$.
Since $e^{e^C}>1$ and $0<e^{-e^C}<1$, the general solution is $y=a^{x}$ with $a>0$ and $a\neq 1$.